# Codeigniter view vs index

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am following this basic [tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html) on Codeigniter about serving up static pages. I followed all the steps and am at this one:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

     public function view($page = 'home')
     {
         if (! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
             // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
             show_404();
         }

         $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

         $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
         $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
         $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
     }
}
```

I copied and pasted it to see the view I made but it gives me a `404 Page Not Found`. I looked at other tutorials and they seem to use an index function and not the view function.

For example I changed the above to the following, simply renamed `view` to `index`:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($page = 'home')
    {
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Now works properly. Why does the tutorial code not work properly?

Comment: Did you set: $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';?

Comment: No. How does that affect it?

Comment: you can study on routing from http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the route in order for the framework to pick up which method to call on the object you define as a controller. That's how the framework works.

Index is a default route, so it doesn't have to be defined. But anything else does.

Comment: @RobertRocha find routes.php in your application/config directory. There's already welcome route so you should find out how to use it. If not check the manual.

Answer (score 1):

This is late but because I also stumbled upon this issue when following the tutorial and this post when figuring it out I will tell you that the tutorial is misleading and/or a bit incomplete.

- First you make a php file to act as controller, must start with uppercase.
- Second, don't load any views until you are comfortable. Make a public method index that echo some text, say you will load the starting page there. In the same file make a second method, all should start in lowercase, name it anything you want, echo something from it as well.
- Now you access the them by typing your address, say:

  ```
  localhost/index.php/lowercaseyourcontrollername/yourdefinedsecondmethodname
  ```

  If you dont specify a method it will process the index method.

  You can edit your routes.php, optionally,  for one reason only and that is to set default_controller, make it equal to your controller name in lowercase. That way if you access your website at root address it will return your controller by default.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'yourcontrollernameinlowercase';
```

Looks like it is really simple now but if its coupled with ambiguous directions it can really waste time.